# Angular 2 [(ngModel)] Not working

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-components

NET Core and Angular 2 application. I have successfully communicated with a web API controller and can log the object in the console.

However when I attempt to log the component in the ts file or access its properties with the [(ngModel)] I am unsuccessful.

Any advice on how to successfully access the object properties in the HTML would be great thanks. Here is my code:

user.service.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
    import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
    import { APP_CONFIG, IAppConfig } from './app.config';
    import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable()
    export class UserService {

        constructor(private http: Http, @Inject(APP_CONFIG) private config: IAppConfig) { }

//SUCCESSFULLY LOG JSON OBJECT HERE
        public getCurrentUser = (): Observable<any> => {
            return this.http
                .post(this.config.apiEndpoint + "currentUser")
                .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
                .do(x => console.log(x));
        }
    }
```

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../../user.service';
import { AngUser } from '../../ang-user';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    selector: 'home-page',
    templateUrl: './app/components/home/home.component.html',
    providers: [UserService]
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(public userService: UserServicer) { }
    public value: any;

    showObject(): void {
          console.log(this.value.id);
          console.log(this.value.userName);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.userService.getCurrentUser()
            .subscribe(data => this.value = data,
           error => console.log(error),
           () => console.log('Get User complete!'));

       this.showObject();
    }



}
```

home.component.html

```
<!-- THIS FAILS TO SHOW ANYTHING -->
        My Values: <ul>
            <li [(ngModel)]="value">
                <span>{{value.id}} {{value.userName}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: Surprisingly no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove **`[(ngModel)]="value"`** from **`li`**

```
 <li >
   <span>{{value.id}} {{value.userName}}</span>
 </li>
```

Comment: what do you see inside this.value?

Comment: I have adjusted the home component to log the object. When it runs I see the Id and the userName as I should

Comment: it should work if you remove the ngModel , no other valid reason. do you see any errors in console

Comment: double check after removing ngModel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142416/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-ryeguy).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- if u get only one object -->
<!--this.value = [{ id: 1, name: 'pbt1' }];-->

My Values: <ul>
    <li>
        <span>{{value[0].id}} {{value[0].name}}</span>
        <input [(ngModel)]="value[0].name" />

    </li>
</ul>

<!-- if u get more than one  -->
<!--this.value = [{ id: 1, name: 'pbt1' }, { id: 2, name: 'pbt2' },{ id: 3, name: 'pbt3' }];-->
My Values: <ul >
    <li *ngFor="let v of value">
        <span>{{v.id}} {{v.name}}</span>
        <input [(ngModel)]="v.name" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Working plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/5vx0tzrfh5Kc7YTU7ixE?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: This comment is from review channel. I am not asking for a plunker, rather I asking some code explanation that how your code works. It's helps who asked and future readers to know how your code actually works.